# Simple Python Script to Rename and Move Images in a folder in an Ascending Order(0-n)

Tags: python, sorting, directory, organized

This solution is designed to make it easier to organize and manage image folders. I had a very unorganized image folder for training a machine learning model. I needed to sort it and rename all the files within it.
To achieve this, I wrote a simple Python script that iterates through the files, checks if they are in .jpg format, and renames them in ascending order, starting with 'image1.jpg,' 'image2.jpg,' and so forth. Additionally, the script moves the renamed images to a new folder named 'renamed_images_folder' within the same directory.

this my py code:

```
import os

def rename_images(folder_path):
    #   Check if the given folder exists
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        return "The folder does not exist."

    #   Create a new folder to store the renamed images
    new_folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "renamed_images_folder")
    if not os.path.exists(new_folder_path):
        os.makedirs(new_folder_path)

    #   Iterate through all files in the folder
    for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_path)):
        #   Check if the file is a .jpg image
        if filename.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
            old_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            new_filename = f"image{i+1}.jpg"
            new_path = os.path.join(new_folder_path, new_filename)
            os.rename(old_path, new_path)

    return f"Images renamed and moved to '{new_folder_path}'."

# Example usage
folder_path = '/path/to/your/image/folder'  #   Replace with the actual path to your image folder
print(rename_images(folder_path))
```

[image: Output:]

[image: How it looks after]

Comment: What is your question? Also, are you aware of the *glob* and/or *pathlib* modules. Either of those would make this task trivial